# Does 'git squash' (after pushing) rewrite the history?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, squash, git-rewrite-history

I'm working on a separate branch for a *feature*.

Now I want this feature in my *main* branch, but just having all the commits squashed to a single one (with a recap into the commit message).

The thing is that **I already `push`ed the branch to `remote`**.
So I'm not sure if I can perform a `git merge --squash feature` (from the *main* branch) or **if that could rewrite my git history**.

I don't get if `git merge --squash` **will just create a new commit** (containing, as a patch, all the changes of my merged branch. So in a *safe way*), or if **it will remove the old commits from my branch** or just **do any alteration to the git history**. (I want to avoid that cause I work in team).

Should I maybe opt for a `commit-range cherry-pick`, instead of a `git squash`? (but the cherry-pick would just copy all the commits without squashing them)

Or merging with squash is fine? (even after a push to the remote feature-branch)

#### I want to integrate my *feature* branch, as a single commit (possibly having all the commit messages that I get with `--squash`) in my *main* branch, but without rewriting the history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No history is rewritten. From the high-level commands, only `git rebase` and `git commit --amend` perform history rewrites.

`git merge --squash` simply prepares a working tree that contains all information from the branch you want to merge, just as the documentation says:

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit or move the HEAD, nor record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit. This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).